# What are good ways to convert SQL query results into a LaTeX table?

Tags: tables, statistics, sql

**Background**

I'm doing some data analysis on a large dataset on a local SQL server. A substantial proportion of that analysis is tabular stuff: frequency tables and the like which summarize various aspects of key variables.

I do all my writeups in a LaTeX environment (Overleaf, compiling with XeLaTeX), which means I'm often bringing stuff over from SQL (and from R, where I do the other part of my analysis) into TeX documents.

**The Problem**

In many cases, I'll try to structure my SQL queries so that they result in exactly the table I'm looking for.

My question for the community is this: do you guys have favorite, neat, or preferred ways to turn the result of a SQL query into a LaTeX table?

**What I've tried**

Take a simple Postgres database that looks like this:

[image: db]

And say that I wanted a simple table that added up the number of errors for each `id`:

```sql
select id as "ID", sum(errors) as "Sum of errors"
from d
group by id
```

Yielding something like this in the DataGrip output viewer:

[image: dg_result]

All well and good, but how to get it into LaTeX?

The main way I've tried is functional, but clunky:

1. I use Datagrip's "export data" function next to the output window to copy the table to the clipboard, like so:

[image: clipboard]

2. I then paste it into this website, [Latex Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables), which then spits out some LaTeX code (after I tell the site to add a border around the cells of the table):

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
ID                                            & Sum of errors                                   \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}a\\ b\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}56\\ 12\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Yielding a neat little result in my document:

[image: result]

So like I said, this is all functional, but since I'm a competent but ultimately quite novice SQL and LaTeX user, I wanted to ask the community whether they had anything better or quicker. I'm thinking that outputting these tables into CSV form might do the trick, but the landscape of CSV-related packages for TeX environments is bewildering.

(FYI: I posted a version of this query over on StackOverflow. Hoping to cast as wide a net as possible.)

Comment: You may be able to use LuaLaTeX with a PostgreSQL library for Lua to run the queries directly from LaTeX and collect the results to construct a table. I doubt that you can do this from Overleaf however, this is (understandably) a rather restricted environment, so you probably need to use a local LaTeX installation. I'm also not sure how much code/libraries/tutorials are already available for this kind of thing, if it has to be built from scratch it is rather broad for a StackExchange question.

Comment: +1 from me though because I think it is interesting :)

Comment: There is also https://ctan.org/pkg/nlatexdb which may be useful (although it seems a bit unmaintained)

Comment: I have never understood why people use table generator sites, they generates over complicated latex and the input is no easier than standard latex input. If you modify your sql to put an `&` after the ID and  `\\ ` after the value then you can directly process the sql output in latex, no cutting and pasting or convrsion required

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the comment! It sounds like it's valuable but tbh I'm not sure I fully follow you.

Comment: @logjammin my sql is rusty but surely you can modify your select statement to output  each row in the form `a & 56 \\ `  rather than the markdown table that you show  `| a | 56 |` if so you can just use `\begin{tabular}{ll}\input{the-file-written-by-sql}\end{tabular}`

Comment: Ahah, I see -- thanks @DavidCarlisle. I'm gonna try implementing this later today and if it works, I'll let you know so you can post it as an answer. (If not, I'll post myself and credit you, of course.)

Answer (score 3):

Because you use R, and R can do SQL queries, and R can produce LateX tables, and with `knitr` it is possible to make the tables directly inside the Latex source in an R noweb (.Rnw) file:

Test.Rnw:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<test,results='asis',echo=FALSE>>=
xtable::xtable(head(sqldf::sqldf("SELECT * FROM iris")), caption="SQL query.")
@
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Note: This can be compiled easily in Rstudio (with pdflatex, xelatex or lualatex, as you wish) but will not work in Overleaf at least because (a) `sqldf` R package is not installed in Overleaf and (b) the file extension for LateX+R files in this site must be `.Rtex`, not `.Rnw`.

I am sure that there are other R ways to connect to SQL databases, and maybe some of them are available from Overleaf, but I have not explored this way.